# What builds nested parameters in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, post

I am spiking an AngularJS 1.0.8 application, which is doing POST requests to a Rails 3.2.13 server. I did something very similar earlier today with slightly different results.

For the sake of example, the main resource will be Person(name:string).

In the earlier attempt, the submitted attributes for creating a new Person instance were processed by Rails as follows: {"name"=>"John", "person"=>{"name"=>"John"}}

In the later attempt, the submitted attributes were processed as follows: {"name"=>"John", "person"=>{}}

In the outbound request from my browser, the request bodies look identical: {"name":"John"}

I would like to know which part of Rails decides what to use for nested parameters, so that I may figure out why these two implementations seem to differ.

Comment: Please show us the code that you're using to make the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the attr_accessor fields on the newer version of the model did not correspond with the fields being sent with the client POST. Those fields are being used by Rails to populate the nested parameters on such a request.

```
class Person
  attr_accessor :name
end

# request body for a POST to /people
{"name":"John","age":"23"}

# request parsed and nested in Rails route
{"name"=>"John", "age"=>"23", "person"=>{"name":"John"}}
```

My assumption, based on what I have read in related nested-param questions and docs, is that fields and associations on ActiveRecord models are used to decide the structure of nested parameters.